# Hide Android Context Menu Item

Tags: android, contextmenu

Another newbie question.  I have a context menu that I apply for a ListView that simply allows the user to move items up or down, or delete the item.

I have code in onContextItemSelected() to prevent things from moving up past top or bottom of the list, etc., but I'd rather hide the context menu items in the first place if (for instance) the top item in the list is selected.

I assume that I need to do this in onCreateContextMenu, but I'm not sure how.

Here is my onCreateContextMenu code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mycontextmenu, menu);
}
```

Thanks,
wTs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a context menu is opened for a `ListView`, `menuInfo` will contain an object of type `AdapterContextMenuInfo`, which gives you information about which item in the list was clicked. If it is the first or the last item, you can simply remove the corresponding entries from the context menu, though I'm not quite sure what happens if no entries are left.

Comment: For future searches... use AdapterContextMenuInfo adapterInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

Comment: And if you don't want to display any context menu for a particular item based on which row was asked for context, just have your onCreateContextMenu() return before inflating your menu.

Answer (score 14):

In your `onCreateContextMenu` method, you need to get the menu items that you potentially want to hide and set them as not visible based on the list positions.

Something like this:

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

if(info.position < 1) {
   myLocationMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.myLocation);
   myLocationMenuItem.setVisible(enable);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution for a `PopupMenu` just in case somebody is seeking for it as I did. Here I have 3 buttons in `menu` layout file for `PopupMenu` and I remove some of them in some cases:

```
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, this.actionButton);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_resume_view, popup.getMenu());

    Menu menu = popup.getMenu();
    if (this.resume.isPublished()) {
        menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_button_publish);
    }
    else {
        menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_button_unpublish);
        menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_button_update_publish_date);
    }

    popup.show();
```

When you use `PopupMenu` `onPrepareOptionsPanel` is not called. So you have to get menu items by `id` while creating `PopupMenu` and remove those, that should not be available in a particular case.

Comment: Hi any Idea how can I remove the title space if we are using only icons? https://gist.github.com/mediavrog/9345938

Comment: `menu.getItem(int i)` expects index but `menu.removeItem(int i)` expects the id. smh

Answer (score 1):

You can Disable a particular item if you want to.

```
@Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
     {
                AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

                int position = info.position;

                // use this position to decide your item clicked

                menu.clear();
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu Title");
                String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                        R.array.menu_context);


                for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++)
                {
                    menu.add(Menu.NONE, i , i, menuItems[i]);
                }
               menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(**Conditional check**);
               menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(**Conditional check**);
               menu.getItem(2).setEnabled(**Conditional check**);
     }
```